# how to verify the end of a tree relation in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How is possible to check the end of a tree relation using the traversing methods from jquery? Example:

```
<table id="t1">
 <tr id="tr1">
   <td>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr2">
   <td>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tr3">
   <td>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How I can know if after `tr3` are coming more `<tr>` ?  I will like that the code answer with something like yes or not, I mean, the question to the system is: has `tr3` a next brother? And the method `next()` could answer yes or not or something like this. Is this possible?
THX!

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).next().length > 0` means there is another sibling

Comment: or if it's specifically tr3 you can use `$('#tr3').next().length>0`